# Selenium remote driver unable to find geckodriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, geckodriver

I'm trying to launch a remote Firefox session with Selenium. Here's the code:

```
def Mozilla():
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as Options_Mozilla
    sys.path.append("/opt/app/venv/bin")
    ff_options = Options_Mozilla()
    ff_options.add_argument("--headless")
    ff_options.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
    ff_options.set_preference("network.proxy.http", "some_address")
    ff_options.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", 8080)
    ff_options.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl", "some_address")
    ff_options.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port", 8080)
    #profile.update_preferences()
    #builtins.browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_options=ff_options)
    #builtins.browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=ff_options)
    builtins.browser = webdriver.Remote(command_executor="http://some_other_address/wd/hub", desired_capabilities=ff_options.to_capabilities())
```

When the code is executed I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Creditview_PL.py", line 15, in <module>
    DS.Mozilla()
  File "/home/ad.ing.net/ji34ix/Projects/DS/DziadowskieSelenium.py", line 35, in Mozilla
    builtins.browser = webdriver.Remote(command_executor="http://172.22.164.33:4444/wd/hub", desired_capabilities=ff_options.to_capabilities())
  File "/opt/app/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/opt/app/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 251, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/opt/app/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/opt/app/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/jgraham/wires. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/jgraham/wires
```

To my surprise when I use this code (without remote driver):

```
def Mozilla():
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as Options_Mozilla
    sys.path.append("/opt/app/venv/bin")
    ff_options = Options_Mozilla()
    ff_options.add_argument("--headless")
    ff_options.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
    ff_options.set_preference("network.proxy.http", "some_address")
    ff_options.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", 8080)
    ff_options.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl", "some_address")
    ff_options.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port", 8080)
    builtins.browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=ff_options)
```

Everything works ! No issues with finding the geckodriver at all.

I also confirm that the folder with geckodriver is in Path. It has to be, otherwise the second code would not be able to work. Common internet knowledge advised to set webdriver.gecko.driver system property but the example code didn't look like Python. As you can see I used sys.path.append but it didn't help at all.

```
Some versions:
Mozilla Firefox 60.1.0
geckodriver 0.21.0
selenium==3.13.0
```

Configuration of the grid node:

```
java -jar /opt/Selenium_grid/selenium-server-standalone-2.49.1.jar -role node -port 5555 -maxInstances=10 -Dwebdriver="opt/app/venv/bin" &> nodelog1.txt &
```

So, can anyone please help me figure out why the remote driver can't find the geckodriver ?

Answer (score 0):

> To my surprise when I use this code (without remote driver):Everything
>   works ! No issues with finding the geckodriver at all. I also confirm
>   that the folder with geckodriver is in Path. It has to be, otherwise
>   the second code would not be able to work.

You are comparing two different modes of execution. The second variant basically attempts at opening a firefox browser in the same machine from where you python test case started running.

The first variant basically is attempting at opening a firefox browser in a remote machine ( Here I am assuming that your grid is running on a different machine). So what is happening here is that Selenium is basically telling you it cannot find geckodriver in the remote machine (A selenium node to be specific).

To fix this problem, you have two options:

1. Add the location of geckodriver binary to your `PATH` variable on the remote selenium node, kill your selenium node, close the terminal and open up a new one (so that the `PATH` is freshly read), and restart your node.
2. Add the JVM argument at the beginning of your node start command. Something like `java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=opt/app/venv/bin -jar /opt/Selenium_grid/selenium-server-standalone-2.49.1.jar -role node -port 5555 -maxInstances=10 &> nodelog1.txt &`

PS: You are using a very old version of Selenium (2.49.1) on the selenium grid side. Please consider upgrading to the latest version (3.14.0 as of today)

Comment: Thank you for your time end effort. I have already solved the problem. Since I was just testing the grid everything was set up on a single machine. The hub and geckodriver were trying to listen on the same port, so nodes were not able to pass instructions to the driver. Looks like they were sent back to the hub :) When I changed the port of the hub everything started to work properly. Also thank you for pointing out the version of the grid, it's upgraded now.